# How to convert an azure data factory string type variable into datetime format

Tags: azure, variables, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

** I had a string type variable in azure data factory which is storing datetime format from a lookup activity**
but after that i need to compare that value inside the variable with a datetime. how can i convert it into datetime format

i tried this but i am getting an error i will post the code and error below

`varible--string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[1].CREATED_DATE)` variable i created which converts datetime into string variable

`query-select * from sampletable where modified_date >=` **formatDateTime(variables('createddate'),"o")**```
this is the code i tried for comparing and to convert it into datetime format

`ERROR`
**Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: ''variables' is not a recognized built-in function name.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message='variables' is not a recognized built-in function name.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=195,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=10,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=195,State=10,Message='variables' is not a recognized built-in function name.,},],'**

Comment: try to enclose `variables` with `@{}`. Something like `@{variables('createddate')}`

Comment: Here is a similar sample query `@{concat('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] WHERE ModifiedDate <=', formatDateTime(variables('createddate'),'o'))}` try and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as per the below sample

```
@{concat('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] WHERE ModifiedDate <=', formatDateTime(variables('createddate'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))}
```

Equivalent to:

```
SELECT TOP (10) * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] WHERE ModifiedDate <=2021-10-27
```

See official doc: [Functions in expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#functions-in-expressions)

[image]

[image]

---

**But If you try as per default format 'o' in formatDateTime() function**

```
@{concat('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] WHERE ModifiedDate <=', formatDateTime(variables('createddate'),'o'))}
```

You might see the below error:

[image]

[image]

Try to refer [formatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatdatetime) and generate a query sutable for datetime format in your database.